# Exclude directories from coverage in AxoCover coverage report

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, code-coverage, opencover

I have Project for which I am using AxoCover for coverage report.

After the test cases are successfully passed the coverage report is generated and the coverage% for Classes, Methods, Branches, and Lines are  given.

In the coverage process, it is also taking the migrations and some system generated files into consideration.

I have tried in the settings to exclude the directories but the report generation is getting filed.

Can someone help me in solving this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the [source code of AxoCover](https://github.com/axodox/AxoCover) but I don't see how the exclude could even work. I tried all the possible path possibilities (Full Path, Partial, backward/forward slash, folder name, etc.).

I ended up using a workaround for now, since AxoCover settings uses the following
`System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute`

[image: AxoCover_ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute]

You can use an annotation in the classes you want to exclude

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
static class Program
{
    // ...
}
```

It's not ideal since you have to do it on a Per Class basis, but for a small project it can be alright.

In my case I wanted to exclude all those auto-generated classes from Windows Form project.